# Why does Entity Framework Core generate navigation property if there is no foreign key?

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have this table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE Categories
(
    Id INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    Name VARCHAR(100),
    CONSTRAINT PK_Category_Id PRIMARY KEY (Id)
)

CREATE TABLE Products
(
    Id INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    IdCategory INT NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT FK_Products_IdCategory__Categories_Id 
            FOREIGN KEY(IdCategory) REFERENCES Categories(Id),
    Name VARCHAR(100), 
    Price DECIMAL(18,2),
    ImageUrl VARCHAR(256),
    CONSTRAINT PK_Product_Id PRIMARY KEY (Id)
)
```

[I execute the following command in the Package Manager Console:](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/create-model-for-existing-database-in-ef-core.aspx)

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=FOO-PC\SQL2014XP;Database=fooDatabase;Trusted_Connection=True;" 
    Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models
```

Entity Framework Core generates the following domain classes:

```
public partial class Categories
{
    public Categories()
    {
        Products = new HashSet<Products>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Products> Products { get; set; }
}

public partial class Products
{
    public Products()
    {
        OrderItems = new HashSet<OrderItems>();
        ShoppingCartItems = new HashSet<ShoppingCartItems>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int IdCategory { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal? Price { get; set; }
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }

    public virtual Categories IdCategoryNavigation { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Items> Items { get; set; }        
}
```

My question are:

1. Why does EF Core generate `public virtual ICollection<Products> Products { get; set; }` in the `Categories` class?
2. Is it possible to prevent generation this property `Products`?

Comment: But there is a FK in Products that points at Categories.  When you have two tables that have a FK between them you get navigation properties going in both directions.  Why would you not want that?  Also it looks like there's also a Items table with a FK to Products, thus the Items navigation property in Products.  Do you want to get rid of that too?

Comment: @juharr I would like to delete a navigation proprety `Categories.Products` because of this [circular navigation properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58034555/how-to-avoid-circular-navigation-properties-in-entity-framework-core/58037399#58037399). So after your comment, I think that all my code is correct and implemented correctly. Feel free to answer and I'll mark your reply as an answer. Thanks.